# How to make Sandia National Laboratories' NuMAD usable in Linux?

Tags: matlab

The set-up for the M-file version of the `Numerical Manufacturing And Design Tool (NuMAD v2.0) for Wind Turbine Blades` is elaborated in p. 16-17 of the [User Guide](http://energy.sandia.gov/wp-content/gallery/uploads/NuMAD_UserGuide_SAND2012-7028.pdf).

Although the guide states in p. 15 that:

> The following are minimal requirements to run NuMAD: Windows or Linux OS ...

Following these steps in a Linux OS results in file saving errors during  a project.

How could one make sure NuMAD can run in a Linux OS smoothly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you followed the set-up steps in the guideline correctly, two additional subtle changes will ensure this:

1. Make sure that **no** file separator remains at the end of the path variable `SNL_NuMAD_Toolbox_path = ...` in `snl.m`:
2. Change the two occasions of `app.settings.job_path = fullfile(pn,'\');` in the file `NuMAD/NuMAD_main.m` to `app.settings.job_path = fullfile(pn,'/');`

Comment: And if you use [`filesep`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filesep.html) instead of a hard-coded symbol, it'll remain cross-platform compatible. Did you think of sending this back as a path (or pull request or whatever they use)?